# Standalone Java Bitcoin Miner - Does it Exist?

Tags: java, cpuminer

I am a java developer, and currently am looking to create a standalone java class that will let people mine Bitcoin using CPU, but I have no idea if such already exists. I have found one for LiteCoin, but that's all

Comment: CPU mining for Bitcoin became infeasible many years ago. You are competing with high end ASICs each of which is probably 1000000 x faster than a high end CPU at computing hashes for Bitcoin mining.

Comment: doesn't matter, my machines do not have gpus in them @Red

Comment: @KyoungwanWoo using a CPU to mine, you will spend money on electricity, but not ever generate enough hashes to get paid out anything whatsoever. So in that regard, it probably does matter to most people.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it Exist?

No

This is because a Java app that uses the CPU to attempt to mine Bitcoin will not be able to mine Bitcoin. There is no good incentive for anyone to create such a thing.